# Mod_rewrite combine default path with www. and https redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to reduce the number of redirects on our website. I already managed to combine some of our redirect code (forcing www. and https://), but I also need to add a default path (/en/) in case there is none.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The other bit of code I want to implement is this:

```
RewriteRule   "^/$"  /en/
```

So if there's no path or arguments given, it needs to redirect to /en/. (Now I do this in PHP, meaning almost every person typing "example.com" gets two redirects, where one should really be enough)

My goal is to combine these rules into one single redirect. Is that possible?

Finally, I also have an internal rewrite rule, which is likely irrelevant for the question above, but I'll add it for completeness:

```
RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$/? index.php?rewrite=$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: htaccess doesnt deal with the leading slash, you have to remove this from pattern. To match against the current directory ie : homepage ,just use this pattern **^$**

Comment: What I'm trying to do is: combine the www. and https rewrite with a default path redirect. If someone opens up the website root "/", then send them to "/en/". This is not a question about slashes.

Comment: Yes, because there is never a slash at the beginning of the RewriteRule left test uri in .htaccess. And so it is never `^/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/en%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This also did the trick, although Croises' answer was a bit more brief. :)

Comment: Actually I realized this solution actually visually added the /en/ for the user, while the other solution didn't.

Answer (score 1):

You can use (in this order):

```
RewriteRule ^$  /en/

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If this is a language test, you can also test the values (ex with: en, fr or de) and change the first line in

```
RewriteRule !^(en|fr|de)/  /en/ [NC]
```

Comment: Cheers, I had no idea what that check mark was for. Now I know. There's not even a hover effect. :)